# First letter moving undesirably with transition + transform (Firefox)

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a list of `div` elements with a big letter (A, B, C or D) and `span` (description) inside. I would like to center these `span` elements horizontally respect to each parent `div`, but keeping a fixed distance among all big letters. I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

The centering part is done with:

```
span{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

But when I apply a simple `transition` (`opacity` for example) to `div` elements, the first letter in `span` elements is moved from it's place. If I remove the `transition` or `transform` property the issue goes away, but I need both (`transform` for centering).

> **Question:** How to fix the issue with `transition` and `transform`, or how to center `span` elements without `transform`, but keeping the fixed distance among big letters?

Here is the code, and a [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/wgbe14vm/9/):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="elements">
    <div>A<span>Description</span></div>
    <div>B<span>Really Long Description</span></div>
    <div>C<span>Description</span></div>
    <div>D<span>Description</span></div>
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
.elements{
    margin-left: 50px;
    div{
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 40px;
        margin: 0 10px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        transition: 0.3s;
        &:hover{
            opacity: 1;
            span{
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
        span{
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            transition: 0.3s;
            font-size: 15px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            pointer-events: none;
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce this behavior in your demo in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 40.0.3 in Ubuntu, just in case.

Comment: Do you want this https://jsfiddle.net/wgbe14vm/1/?

Comment: @divy3993 The distance is not the same among A, B, C, etc. [See here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/wgbe14vm/2/).

Comment: Try putting `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` on the span element

Comment: @Jackson The problem persists.

Comment: Is it ok to give some defined width to `div` ?

Comment: @divy3993 Yes, you can define a `width` to `div` elements, but not in `span`.

Comment: @Imagonzalves. Posted the Answer is that what you want?

Comment: @Imagonzalves Sorry still can't understand what you want? You told distance between A,B & C  not same [here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/wgbe14vm/2/). So you were talking about the distance between div's?

Comment: @divy3993 I'm talking about distance among A, B, C & D letters, no the whole `div` (red border).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a way to make work properly `transition` and `transform` properties (Firefox at least). But I found a way to center each `span` elements inside it parent `div`, keeping distance among big letters (A, B, C & D).

See the [SOLUTION DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/wgbe14vm/11/), and the code added (SCSS):

```
$div-width: 40px;
$span-width: 200px;

.elements{
    div{
        width: $div-width;           // fixed width
        text-align: center;          // center text
        span{
            width: $span-width;                     // big fixed width
            left: -($span-width/2 - $div-width/2);  // -(200px / 2 - 40px / 2)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on [compatibility requirements](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), you could always use the flex box model, and it's handy `justify-content` property, like so:

```css
.elements {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex; /*Only one out of the above that's really needed...*/
  justify-content: space-around;/*Only one out of the below that's really needed...*/
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.elements >div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 30pt;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s opacity;
}
.elements >div:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.elements >div >div {
  font-size: 12pt;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements">
  <div>A
    <div>Description</div>
  </div>
  <div>B
    <div>Long Description</div>
  </div>
  <div>C
    <div>Description</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Your question has a very nice solution, tables! While they should only be used for tabular data semantically, they do have some nice display properties, and they'be been used [since forever](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) so compatibility is not an issue.

```css
body{
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
.elements{display:table-row;}
.elements >div {
  width:20%; /*100% / Number of cells*/
  display:table-cell;
  padding:0 10px; /*There needs to be a little spacing otherwise it looks bad :) */
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 30pt;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s opacity;
}
.elements >div:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.elements >div >div {
  font-size: 12pt;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements">
  <div>A
    <div>Description</div>
  </div>
  <div>B
    <div>Long Description</div>
  </div>
  <div>C
    <div>Description</div>
  </div>
  <div>D<div>Description</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As you can see in [this DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/Lxa58nwd/1/), the distance among A, B, C & D letters is not the same. Also the distance is not fixed (change depending on window `width` size). And I'm not downvoting you, btw, good try.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what your question is now, the distances are all the same. Please clarify with an annotated picture. Sorry the responsive distance was implied in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but still the same problem. The big letters (A, B, C, D) are not separated by the same distance. If you put a really long description ([DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/558xLxxz/)) you can see that. Check my answer to see a possible solution I found to this issue. Anyway I'm upvoting your effort, thanks for your time :)